# Tikz labels for axis \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am wondering if there is an easier way to build the axis for my diagram. I do use the \begin{axis} \end{axis} for graphs as well, but I am wondering if there is a line of code that I could use to fill in each tick mark on the x and y axis without manually putting them in.  Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (2.5,20.7) node {\footnotesize \(f(x)\)};

\begin{scope}[transform shape,shift ={(2,19.2)}]
\draw[step=1, color=gray] (-1.5,-0.5) grid (3.5,4.5);
\draw[line width=0.05cm,->,>=stealth] (-1.5,0) -- (3.5,0) node[anchor=north] {\footnotesize \(x\)};
\draw[line width=0.05cm,->,>=stealth] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=east] {\footnotesize \(y\)};
\path (-0.15,-0.15) node {\footnotesize \(0\)};
\path (-1,-0.18) node {\footnotesize \(-1\)};
\path (1,-0.18) node {\footnotesize \(1\)};
\path (2,-0.18) node {\footnotesize \(2\)};
\path (3,-0.18) node {\footnotesize \(3\)};
\path (-0.18,1) node {\footnotesize \(1\)};
\path (-0.18,2) node {\footnotesize \(2\)};
\path (-0.18,3) node {\footnotesize \(3\)};
\path (-0.18,4) node {\footnotesize \(4\)};
\draw[blue, line width=0.4mm, samples=1000, domain=-1.1:3] plot (\x, {\x+2});
\draw[blue,fill=white](1,3) circle(.07);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time,

Nick

Comment: why do you load `graphics` and `graphicx`? I think the second is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the easiest way to do this is with these two lines:

```
\foreach \i in {-1,0,...,3}{node[below right] at (\i,0) {\footnotesize$\i$};
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}{node[above left] at (0,\i) {\footnotesize$\i$};
```

And this is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (2.5,20.7) node {\footnotesize \(f(x)\)};

\begin{scope}[transform shape,shift ={(2,19.2)}]
\draw[step=1, color=gray] (-1.5,-0.5) grid (3.5,4.5);
\draw[line width=0.05cm,->,>=stealth] (-1.5,0) -- (3.5,0) node[anchor=north] {\footnotesize \(x\)};
\draw[line width=0.05cm,->,>=stealth] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=east] {\footnotesize \(y\)};

\foreach \i in {-1,0,...,3}\node[below right] at (\i,0) {\footnotesize$\i$};
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}\node[above left] at (0,\i) {\footnotesize$\i$};
\draw[blue, line width=0.4mm, samples=1000, domain=-1.1:2.5] plot (\x, {\x+2});
\draw[blue,fill=white](1,3) circle(.07);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. Works great!

Answer (score 2):

With `pgfplots` grid labels are automatic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    x=1cm, y=1cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-1.5, xmax=3.5,
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=4.5,
    grid=major,
]
\addplot[blue, domain=-1.1:3, line width=0.4mm] {x+2};
\addplot[blue, only marks, fill=white] coordinates {(1,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was aware of this using pgfplots. I was working with this in tikzpicture instead. I work with both as a teacher and I am trying to learn more about both.